# How to emulate QQ plot from ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantile, ggpubr

There are plenty of threads here about using a QQ plot, but I'm trying to figure out how to hand calculate one and in the process I wanted to emulate the one used in `ggpubr`, as it looks better than the base R version. I have so far at least seemingly produced a QQ plot in base R using this method:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

#### Organize Data ####
x <- sort(iris$Petal.Length)
rank <- c(1:150)
perc.scale <- scale(rank)
df <- data.frame(x,
                 rank,
                 perc.scale)

#### Plot in Base R ####
plot(perc.scale,
     x,
     xlab = "Theoretical Quantiles",
     ylab = "Sample Quantiles",
     main = "Normal Q-Q Plot")
```

The result is mostly similar to the base R version, but I haven't figured out the QQ line.

[image]

Similarly, I can just use `ggqqplot(x)` on my data to get this:

[image]

But when I try to reproduce it in `ggplot` with my hand-calculated data:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=perc.scale,
             y=x))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              color = "black",
              se = F,
              linewidth = .5)+
  theme_pubr()+
  labs(x="Theoretical",
       y="Sample")
```

It still looks totally different:

[image]

**My main questions are 1) how do I get the correct regression line and 2) how do I get the standard error area to show up?** I'm also unsure of why the `ggplot` version looks rotated compared to the `ggpubr` version, but that isn't as important for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `stat_qq_line` to get a qq-plot in `ggplot` like this:

```r
#### Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

#### Organize Data ####
x <- sort(iris$Petal.Length)
rank <- c(1:150)
perc.scale <- scale(rank)
df <- data.frame(x,
                 rank,
                 perc.scale)

ggplot(df, aes(sample = x)) +
  stat_qq() +
  stat_qq_line() +
  theme_pubr()+
  labs(x="Theoretical",
       y="Sample")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

You could use [`qqplotr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qqplotr/vignettes/introduction.html) with `stat_qq_band` to add confidence interval like this:

```r
#### Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(qqplotr)

ggplot(df, aes(sample = x)) +
  stat_qq_band() +
  stat_qq_point() +
  stat_qq_line() +
  theme_pubr()+
  labs(x="Theoretical",
       y="Sample")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I've upvoted your answer because it does provide an option, but perhaps I wasn't clear enough about what I really wanted. Specifically I am looking to hand-calculate the QQ line, not use an automatic function. The point for me is to be able to demonstrate how it is done rather than automating it (this is to teach students what QQ plots "do"). For example, I have shown how you derive the plot points by standardizing the ranks and plotting against the raw values.

I mainly just need the line. The SE is just a nice addition if possible.